# Copy dropdown menu's data to text box on select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Let's say you have this dropdown menu:

```
<select>
   <option value="10">Apple</option>
   <option value="20">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="name" />
<input type="price" />
```

If user selects "Orange" from the dropdown menu, the textboxes' values should be:

```
<input type="name" value="Orange" />
<input type="price" value="20" />
```

or if it was "Apple", then textboxes' values should be `Apple` and `10`.

Is this possible with Jquery or Jquery Mobile, if yes how?

Comment: Yes, yes it is possible.

Comment: @IMB [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) ;-)

Comment: Well all your answers work, now it will tough to select best answer :-) Thanks!

Comment: @IMB choose PSCoder's, that's the best xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f23uP/

```
$('select').change(function(){

$('input[type=name]').val($('option:selected',this).text());
    $('input[type=price]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Its just one of those days for your probably :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var price = this.value;
    var selText = $("select option:selected").text();

    $("input[type='name']").val(selText);
    $("input[type='price']").val(price);
});
```

Something like that should work

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**:

```
$("#s").on("change",function(){
    $("#text").val($(this).children().filter("option:selected").text());
    $("#price").val($(this).val());
});
```

**Markup**:

```
<select id="s">
   <option value="10">Apple</option>
   <option value="20">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="text" id="price" />
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/NnsDt/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a little confused with types of inputs. This [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) will help.

If I understand you correctly, you want to take the value and the label from the select and store them in a corresponding textbox. Here is my solution:

HTML:

```
<select id="fruit">
   <option></option>
   <option value="10">Apple</option>
   <option value="20">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="price" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#fruit").change(function() {
     var name = $(this).find(":selected").text();
     var price =  $(this).val();
     $("#name").val(name);
     $("#price").val(price);
});
```

Note that this jQuery only binds the fruit `select` for the onchange instead of binding all `select`

Comment: Careful, the input's that need appending to don't have ID's.